# Stop / Kill an Infinite Loop Bash Script at 2:00 PM within the script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Help! I have this simple bash script that is supposed to "exit" / stop executing at 14:00 but it won't work. Would be really grateful for any pointers, suggestions, advices, anything at all! Many thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
if [ `date +%H` -ge 14 ]; then
 exit
fi
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://login:password@1.1.1.1:554/11 -metadata title="Live Cam" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key
sleep 10
done
```

It's all working OK but it won't quit at 2:00 PM as it is supposed to and just keeps on running all clocks around. In fact, I was trying to make it run for 10 hours every day but couldn't come up with anything except for starting it off from a cron job and then stopping it with "if then" statement within the script itself.

Comment: Are you sure `ffmpeg` does not block for some reason? Have you tried adding an echo between `ffmpeg` and `sleep` to check this hypothesis?

Comment: I am not sure how would you echo ffmpeg to sleep or vice versa?

Comment: I mean: Add an `echo X` between the `ffmpeg` and `sleep 10` lines to see your loop is actually looping. If you get `X` in the output every ten seconds or so, then it is running. Else, `ffmpeg` is probably blocking (although I am not familiar with it and can't say if this is possible at all).

Comment: Since we don't know if `ffmpeg` is running once, you could use an `at` job: `echo "kill -9 $$" | at 1400` or, if you want the script to continue, `echo "pkill -9 ffmpeg" | at 1400`.

Comment: wow, this is superb and very simple waltinator. I'll give it a try. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script here by inserting an "echo" in front of ffmpeg and an "echo exiting..." on a separate line before the exit and then alternating the -ge with -le to test both branches and it seems to work flawlessly.

I guess you need to enhance the script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  if [ `date +%H` -ge 14 ]; then
    exit
  fi
  ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://login:password@1.1.1.1:554/11 -metadata title="Live Cam" -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key &
  pid_of_ffmpeg=$!
  sleep 10
  kill -9 $pid_of_ffmpeg
done
```

Which kills ffmpeg with no mercy after 10 seconds.  (You can alter the times of course, or if you want to kill it after %H -gt 14, then do a loop similiar to the main loop after starting ffmpeg).

Comment: Thank you  so much for replying, user56452. Appreciate. I am not sure how do I do a similar to the main loop for ffmpeg? Isn't it already there with date+%H -ge 14? Could you throw in an example of code, please?

Comment: I tried your suggested answer but it doesn't work. It still keeps on running forever and nothing gets killed. I think I have to get this PID first into a variable and then pass it over to this KILL command, is that not right? How do I do that?

Comment: Hey, sorry for answering late :)
But what do you mean "didn't work"? any error?  
The ampersand after the ffmpeg command executes it in the background the next line saves the pid of that process and the last line inside the loop kills the process...